# How to remove border from autofocus input and div element?

Tags: html, css

I tried to do this for an active element:

```
div:active, input:active {
  outline:none
}
```

How can I remove this focus style from input?

Comment: Isn't the answer in the question?

Comment: Use `div:focus` and `input:focus`?

Answer (score 1):

This border is used to show that the element is focused (i.e. you can type in the input or press the button with Enter). You can remove it, though:

```
div:focus, input:focus{
    outline: 0;
}
```